# Linker architecture error using C library inside Swift module

Tags: c, swift, compiler-errors, frameworks, linker

I have an xcode workspace with the following structure:

- A C library `iGLPK` compiled into a framework (dynamic or static, the error persists)
- A dynamic framework `SwiftyGLPK` which has `iGLPK` as a linked framework and provides a Swift wrapper to use the C library
- An xcode project `Frozen` which has `SwiftyGLPK` as a linked framework
- The code that uses the SwiftyGLPK library is in a separate framework target `Model_GLPK` within the `Frozen` project. This framework compiles fine.

The problem comes when I write code within the main `Frozen/ViewController` that calls on `Model_GLPK` and hence down to the C library underneath - it does not compile and produces this linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "SwiftyGLPK.SolveGoal.Minimise (SwiftyGLPK.SolveGoal.Type) -> SwiftyGLPK.SolveGoal", referenced from:
  Frozen.ViewController.viewDidLoad (Frozen.ViewController)() -> () in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I get the same result on the simulator and on device, just the architecture that's not found changes.

I also tried extracting the files from the `Model_GLPK` framework and putting them directly into the `Frozen` target. Now everything compiles fine and there is no longer a linking error, but instead I get a hard crash on run

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error:
->  0x1200c1088 <+0>: brk    #0x3
```

after this instruction:

`dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*)`

Can anyone shed light on what's going on?

Comment: Try using this guide http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, but not an explanation.

I built up the workspace step by step again, starting from having the C library compiled directly inside the main project which worked, then extracting it into a framework, then extracting its Swift wrapper into its own framework, then creating an internal module linked to the wrapper.

Now everything works but I still have no idea why or what's different from before. The whole thing feels really fragile.  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

This article on [module maps for static libraries](http://blog.bjhomer.com/2015/05/defining-modules-for-custom-libraries.html) was helpful, as was [this one](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/). Also this [build settings reference](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/buildsettings.html).